# document.getElementsByTagName:Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript, variables

I wanna make a varible shortcut $$() so that i can use shortcut like $() [jquery] to save code in my project(ALL MY CODE IS PURE JAVASCRIPT).
when i put the string of id or class, it works all right, but when i put the tagName, it shows  Cannot read property 'style' of undefined, it seems that the code is right,help,thanks

One more, is that way to defined a shortcut variable $$() to use in pure javascript environment right way? or is there any best practice to define a global variable like this?

```js
    window.onload = function(){
 function $$(ele){
   var pattern1 = /#/g;
   var pattern2 = /\./g;
   var pattern3 = /!/g;
        var matches = ele.match(/[^#\.!]/g);//array
        var elementS = matches.join("");

        //alert(matches+elementS);
         // console.log(document.getElementsByTagName(elementS));
        
        var spaceExist = /\s/.test(elementS)
   if(pattern1.test(ele)){
    return document.getElementById(elementS);
              
   }else if(pattern2.test(ele)){
    //console.log(elementS);
    return document.getElementsByClassName(elementS);

   }else if(pattern3.test(ele)){
    alert('hi');
    console.log(elementS);
    return document.getElementsByTagName(elementS);
   }else if(spaceExist){
    return document.querySelectorAll(elementS);
   }
  }
  $$('#hme').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  $$('.myp')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  $$('!h2')[0].style.display = 'none';//this not work,shows Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined
}
```

```html
 <h1 id="hme">hi,friend</h1>
 <p class="myp">mmdfdfd</p>
 <h2>hhhhhh</h2>
```

Comment: Note that dot has a special meaning in regex, it matches any character. If you wan to match `.` literally, you have to escape it with a backslash: `\.`.

Comment: @Gothdo, just fix it and still cannot fix my problem,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you stepped through your code? Look at pattern #2:

> var pattern2 = /./g;

That pattern will match any character at all given that's what the period represents in regular expressions - ref: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html.

Therefore, this conditional is satisfied and returns its result:

```
else if(pattern2.test(ele)){
    return document.getElementsByClassName(elementS);
}
```

Given there appears to be no element with a class name of `h2` (which is the value of `elementS`), the return value is `undefined`.

Given that `undefined` has no properties, interrogating for the `style` property will produce the error you are seeing.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i just fixed it from pattern2 = /./g to pattern2 = /\./g, but still cannot work.

Comment: It wouldn't, given you have `alert(hi);` in the conditional block that will execute... `hi` isn't a variable name, so it will bomb out. Delete that line.

Comment: @franklee Spend some time getting to know how Chrome's dev tools work, they will save you a bunch of time in future: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Thanks for your advice^_^

Answer (score 0):

My advise is use one shortcut since you already using `querySelectorAll`:

```
window.$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)
```

or if you rather need first element

```
window.$ = document.querySelector.bind(document)
```

this way you'll be able to do everything you are doing with normal css selectors and not obfuscated `!tag` for just `tag`

If speed actually matters, you will save some ticks by just having two aliases:

```
window.$ = document.querySelector.bind(document)
window.$el = document.getElementById.bind(document)
```

and calling `$el` when you need it specifically, instead of trying to make method polymorph.

Comment: It's just about the speed. getElementById is faster,i think . so i coded all the possibilities.querySelectorAll is for circustances when i input a string with a whitespace in it. By the way , i have get first node and then get style of it if you look at my code,thanks

Comment: @franklee Have you tried to profile it?  The way to deal with it is to cache references to nodes and not touching DOM when not nessessary, instead of writing obfuscated language which you anyway fallback to css selectors.

Comment: @franklee just fyi: https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/233 try to run it. also see they are using `charAt` which is blazing fast compared to regex.

Comment: ,interesting. So by this example of the url, what you mean is we donot need to write a shortcut like $$() to map getElementById() but directly code  getElementById(), right?

Comment: yes,  your code to execute 3 regexes to call one method or another is bigger performance hit than using one method or another.

Comment: So in your edited answer above, we can use $el('theid') to represent docuemnt.getElementById('theid'), which is faster than give it a function to represent it?

Answer (score 0):

Mister Epic's answer spots the main issue.  Your h2 call is getting caught in that if statement, and that's why your error is happening.  You need to make sure it doesn't get caught there, either by creating another pattern, or specifying in your second if statement that your 'ele' doesn't contain an '!'.

After that, in your third if statement:

```
else if(pattern3.test(ele)){
        alert(hi); <---
        console.log(elementS);
        return document.getElementsByTagName(elementS);
```

The problem with this is you're going to alert(hi), but hi isn't defined.  Make sure you wrap it in quotes.
Should be looking good after that.